# How can I get the keys from application.properties and use it in that application.properties

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I need to use this line
File name :- "application.properties"

Here, I used replica set for mongodb(So, data will be stored in both db) and for that purpose I have to give both instance in the uri). [Link of official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.replicaSet)

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://ideation.southcarolina.cloudapp.azure.com:30001,ideation.southcarolina.cloudapp.azure.com:30002/user_demo?replicaSet=idea-mongo-set
```

So, I thought how we can use key value pair in other file, I will use that type in this application.properties file
So, I wrote one line

```
hostname = ideation.southcarolina.cloudapp.azure.com
```

And replace the mongo db uri line by below line

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://${hostname}:30001,${hostname}:30002/user_demo?replicaSet=idea-mongo-set
```

But, it gave **com.mongodb.MongoSocketException** exception. Most probably because it may took whole value as string and can not able to identify ip hostname after spliting in url(hostname:port).

So, is there any way I can access value of a key in application.properties file?

Comment: As first thing, inject the `spring.data.mongodb.uri` property at startup in the main class and output its value. It could help more than guessing.

Comment: Great idea. Thanks

Comment: It is printing as "mongodb://${hostname}:30001,${hostname}:30002/user_demo?replicaSet=idea-mongo-set"

Comment: It is taking the total as a spring

Comment: Yeah. it is working. May be, I have some problem with  db and I thought  this one gave problem. Thank you so much